# CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER - Target Server Connection

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have an SSIS Package that transfers data from source server > target server. This is a straight table to table transfer from one DB to another.

The SSIS Package runs fine from visual studio, however when I run the package from the SQL Server Agent I get the following error:

> CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER' error related to the target server. Login Timeout Expired, Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

I've been reading around online but have been unable to come up with a solution as of yet. I tried to transfer the data using the import/export wizard and that worked without any problems.

Any ideas what is causing the error when running the package using the SQL Agent?

Comment: Does the account used to run the package from SQL Agent have the proper permissions on both servers, databases, tables, etc., that are involved?